# How to invoke mapped `i_CTRL-W` in function

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, insert-mode, functions

First I will describe what I am trying to achieve:

In general I use `set iskeyword+=-` as I see this more usable (one should always put spaces around operators when needed). This is quite helpful, but has one significant disadvantage - it also causes `i_^w` to behave not as expected. So I am trying to write function that would reset `'iskeyword'` to default value, modify it a little and then fire the same functionality as `i_^w`, however I cannot find how to handle "deletion" part.

My attempt

```
func! smart#delete_word() abort
    let l:iskeyword = &iskeyword

    try
        set iskeyword&vim
        set iskeyword-=_

        if col('.') == col('$') - 1
            normal! dvb
        else
            normal! db
        end
    finally
        let &iskeyword = l:iskeyword
    endtry
endfunc
```

However `db`/`dvb` trick isn't always working as expected and sometimes there are some leftovers at the end of the line or some additional characters are deleted.

So question is, how to achieve the same behaviour as `i_^w` in function (worth mentioning that `i_^w` itself will be remapped to this function, so it wouldn't be a solution to just `feedkeys("\<C-w>")`.

Comment: One trick would be to use `norm! i^w` where you insert `^w` with `<c-v><c-w>`

Comment: @statox unfortunately that doesn’t work as it moves cursor one character backwards and `exec "norm! a\<c-w>"` doesn’t work when started in the middle of the line.

Comment: `feedkeys("\<C-w>", 'n')` doesn't map (similar to `normal!`)

Comment: @Mass for whatever reason `feedkeys("\<C-w>", 'n')` didn't work as expected as it deleted single character at the time. However it can be bug in NeoVim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution that seems to work without problems:

```
if col('.') == col('$') - 1
     exec "norm! a\<C-w>\<right>"
else
     exec "norm! i\<C-w>\<right>"
end
```